# Storing PHP server time in mysql row later checking it

Tags: php, mysql

I want to do:

- Store server (not local computer) time inside mysql row.
- Give acces to the page only if user's stored time is with one hour up.

Exemple

- User A gets server's time in HourRow and MinuteRow.  (22:46 ->  HourRow: 22.   Minuterow: 46)
- User A can acces the webpage only when HourRow is not 22. (It doesn't matter if it's less, because servertime goes only forward, not backward)

This is my vision of how I would do it, it is right or it's bad?

```
$Hour = date('H');
$Minute = date('i');
$sql="UPDATE users SET HourRow='$Hour + 1', MinuteRow='$Minute' WHERE username='$user'";


    <?php
    $servertime=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    ?>
    <?php if ($['HourRow'] === servertime('h');) : ?><html>Text</html> else if($['HourRow'] !== $servertime('h');) header('location: https://google.com'); <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You never execute this SQL, but that is even for the best, because you should never concatenate/interpolate PHP variables inside SQL string.

Comment: Why not just store the timestamp and use a `where` clause to compare? Your `else if` also needs an opening PHP tag.